# Date / Night Interval in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin for booking resorts, and in a part of booking it shows box with your search (check in - check out - nights - number of adult,,, etc.. )

i want to show number of days as well.. 
so if total nights is 7 nights, i want to show (8days/7nights) instead of showing (7nights).

here is the php code for this part:

```
<?php
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($from);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($to);
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $nights = $interval->format('%a');
         ?>
```

and showing it like this:

```
<div><?php echo '<b>From:</b> ' . $from . '&nbsp; <b>To:</b> ' . $to . '&nbsp; <b>No. of nights: </b> ' . $nights . ' night(s) ' . ''; ?></div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So... you are looking for help to do `$nights + 1` ?

Comment: Sorry, but im very new to PHP, and i knew it is easy, but i didn't know exactly how to do it...

Comment: So long as it helps you. :-) You may want to play with a few tutorials to help you get used to the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
<?php
    $from = '2000-01-01 12:00:00';
    $to = '2000-01-03 01:00:00';
    $hours = round((strtotime($to) - strtotime($from))/3600, 1);
    $daynight=ceil($hours/12);
    if($daynight%2==0)
    {
        echo $daynight/2 ." Days and ". $daynight/2 ." Nights";
    }
    else
    {
        $ampm = date('A', strtotime('$from'));
        $nights = $daynight/2;
        $days = $daynight/2;
        if(strcasecmp($ampm, "AM"))
            $nights+=1;
        else
            $days+=1;
        echo floor($days) ." Days and ". floor($nights) ." Nights";
    }
?>
```

Although night time is considered from 00:00:00 to 12:00:00  and day is considered from 12:00:00 to 23:59:59